# Entity Framework Migrations - Change Property DataType

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, sqlexception

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 4 web application with Entity Framework 5.0 for data persistence. I am using Code First and Automatic Migrations during development.

As I had to work with an existing database I used this helpful tutorial to create my Domain Classes
[Code First to an Existing Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj200620)

I have a class in my model named **tblcourseapplicant** which has a String property called **ManagerTitle**. I would like to change this datatype to **Int**, and to do this I changed the property in the POCO class

from

```
public string ManagerTitle { get; set; }
```

to

```
public int ManagerTitle { get; set; }
```

and then I changed the property attribute in the relevant Mapping Class (tblcourseapplicantMap) using Fluent API

from

```
this.Property(t => t.ManagerTitle).HasMaxLength(5);
```

to

```
this.Property(t => t.ManagerTitle).IsRequired();
```

I also updated all the data in the database for this particular column so that all the values were converted to integers.

I ran my project and the automatic migrations try to perform this update for me, but it comes back with the following error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ManagerTitle', table
>   'tblcourseapplicant'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

I can't understand why this is, as there are no records in my database table where ManagerTitle is NULL, they have all been assigned an integer value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Folks I am still struggling to find a solution to this problem. I noticed that the error coming back is an **SqlException**. Does anyone have any ideas please? I don't understand what the problem is here, my understanding is that Code First Automatic Migrations should be able to handle this simple property datatype change.

Help!

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? Thanks again.

Comment: You need to seed your data again as this would require table to be empty changing fields to not null and insert new data into it from the seed function. Try to keep the data out of the table for a moment and reset the table then run migration. it would do it successfully then you can insert data back again. Or better use seed functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has the column been defined as nullable in the database?

You can also try making it nullable in the POCO

```
public int? ManagerTitle { get; set; }
```

Comment: I need the column to be NOT NULL though as it is going to be a Foreign Key.

Comment: I ended up with this configuration in my solution - NOT NULL in the database, but int? for Foreign Keys in my POCOs.

Comment: But Code First Migrations should be updating this datatype in the database for me. Something is not right somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When doing a similar update with non-Automatic Migrations the update code would just delete the old column and create a new one without any data migration between renamed (or retyped) properties.

I suspect this might be the case with your issue.